# Iterating over mappings of a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose

```
data Color = Color Int Int Int -- RGB, each R, G and B in [0..255]
  deriving (Show,Eq)

data Coord = Coord Int Int -- x- and y-coordinates of a pixel

data Picture = Picture (Coord -> Color) -- A Picture is just a function mapping a coordinate to its respective pixel color.
```

Now, I need to iterate over all mappings `(Coord, Color)`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I don't really understand what it is that you need to do, but perhaps a `Map Coord Color` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html) might be helpful. If not, perhaps you could elaborate on the question?

Comment: Except that `Int` of course has bounds, if we assume `Int` is unbounded, the number of mappings is endless, it can even have values for certain coordinates and not for others, that does not per se needs to be rectangular. It is therefore not entirely clear to me what you aim to do.

Comment: @MarkSeemann In my exersise I am not allowed to use Maps.

Comment: You would need to call the function on every possible value of `Coord` in order to get the resulting colors. Note that doing so would requiring knowing which values the function is *defined* for, and there's no way to query a function to get that information.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how to convert your `Coord -> Color` function into a concrete mapping in the form of a list `[(Coord, Color)]` then you need to know that in general this is not really possible or at least not practical.

One thing you can do is add two parameters denoting the height and the width of the picture:

```
data Picture = Picture Int Int (Coord -> Color)
```

Then you can convert it into a `[(Coord, Color)]` mapping:

```
getMapping :: Picture -> [(Coord, Color)]
getMapping (Picture width height f) =
  [(Coord x y, f (Coord x y)) | x <- [0..width-1], y <- [0..height-1]]
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to add some more material to my question? Perhaps, that would make answering more on-point.

Comment: Also, I am not allowed to modify the definition of `Picture`, so I cannot use the technique presented in your answer.

Comment: @coderodde there are several things you can add to your question such as: the constraints (like not being able to change the `Picture` type), an honest attempt at solving this exercise, example input and expected output pairs.

Comment: @coderodde given that you're not allowed to modify `Picture` it seems inevitable that there must be some global assumption on the size of the pictures. Otherwise it would not be possible to recover a list from the `Coords -> Color` function.